# Delete parent UserControl when child button is clicked

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am adding a UserControl in a stack Panel and that UserControl contains a button. i am trying to remove that UserControl when it's children button is clicked. But it doesn't work !
**StackPanel**

```
<StackPanel Name="StackPanelContainer" Grid.Row="3"> </StackPanel>
```

**Adding control in StackPanel**

```
private void NewProducModule(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UserControl productModules = new AddProductModule();
    productModules.Name = "Product" + StackPanelContainer.Children.Count;
    StackPanelContainer.Children.Add(productModules);
}
```

**Child Button of UserControl click method**

```
private void DeleteSelfProduct(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement parent=(FrameworkElement)((Button)sender).Parent;
    NewInvoiceControl newInvoiceControl = new NewInvoiceControl();
    newInvoiceControl.StackPanelContainer.Children.Remove(parent);
}
```

Comment: You're creating a `new NewInvoiceControl()`. That's certainly not the one you want to operate on. Your approach is broken in any case. There should be a view model where a data item is deleted, which then results in removal of the UI element that visualizes it.

Comment: NewInvoiceControl is the main container that contains a StackPanel named as "StackPanelContainer" then i am adding another control named "AddProductModule" in StackPanelContainer and this AddProductModule control contains that Button that should delete it's Parent that is dynamically created!

Comment: But if you create a new one, it's not the one which contains your UserControl. You would have to access the parent of `parent` to get the StackPanel where you want to remove a child.

Comment: then how can i reference to my original NewInvoiceControl that contains this StackPanel that contains newly add UserControl to delete this newly added control ? i am beginner !

Comment: It's unclear why you need access to the NewInvoiceControl. `((Panel)parent.Parent).Children.Remove(parent)` should work. Otherwise keep a reference to the NewInvoiceControl somewhere in your code, i.e. by assigning `x:Name`.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help ! it worked .but problem is the parent Control is deleted but it left it's space there ! i mean that when i again add another UserControl it is added under the old UserControl that i have deleted !

Comment: As said, this approach is bad design anyway. Take a look at the [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) article on Microsoft Docs. Then use an ItemsControl with an appropriate ItemTemplate to show a variable number of your UserControls.

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain Set the control's visibility to collapsed before removing it, I think that'll help with the residue space.

Comment: @IneedHelp thanku sir ! that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

try to Clear the StackPanel from it's Children. The StackPanel well Collapsed.

```
private void DeleteSelfProduct(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    StackPanelContainer.Children.Clear(); 
}
```

or you can remove the StackPanel From it parent. if you know the parent.

```
private void DeleteSelfProduct(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    var parent = (StackPanel)StackPanelContainer.Parent;

    parent.Children.Remove(StackPanelContainer); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For actions in your button, it lacks data.
Set the binding to the panel in the command parameter:
`CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}}"`.

In the clicker, extract the panel from the parameter and remove the UserControl from it.
An example from the assumption that the "DeleteSelfProduct" method is in the Code Behind UserControl:

```cs
private void DeleteSelfProduct(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    if (button.CommandParameter is Panel panel)
        panel.Children.Remove(this);
}
```

**P.S.** While this should help, I still advise you to take a closer look at a typical WPF implementation in the MVVM pattern.
You should not (if implemented correctly) create or even simply refer to WPF UI elements in Sharp code.
You only need to prepare data necessary for WPF on Sharpe.
But their presentation (including dynamic creation, modification, etc.) must be fully defined in XAML.
XAML is the core language of WPF.
And you need to explore all of its capabilities: DataContext, Binding, DataTemplate, Style and much more.